# How to make a delay between animations in mecanim?

Tags: unity, mecanim

How to make a delay between animations in mecanim? For example after anim1 ends then there will be a delay then anim2 starts. I tried to increase the exit time but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to extend the Exit Time of the initial state, longer than the clip duration, unless the clip is in loop mode (or disabling the loop via code at a specific point).

I usually prefer this way because adding states in the Mecanim creates visual cluttering, due to the impossibility so far to zoom out in the Animator window. :|

Answer (score 0):

You will need an"intermediate" state (I will call "Idle") without any motion and a speed set to 1

- States : [State1] → [Idle] → [State2]
- Transitions :

  - [State1] → [Idle] : Exit time = 1 ; transition duration = 0 ; no condition
  - [Idle] → [State2] : Exit time = delay ; transition duration = 0 ; no condition

[image: Animator]